# How to set the value of dropdown using jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have a drop down and i want to select its value by value id. I can set by its text but how i can set by value id? I have tried the following code but its not working

```
  $("#ddlUserId").val(id); // not working

  $("#ddlUserId").val("ABC"); // working
```

But if i pass string then its value is selected.How i can set value id?
I have inspected the dropdown, it has all value.
Is there any way to select drop-down value by int id?

Comment: can you create a fiddle for this

Comment: Can you please provide your HTML select structure.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of changing the select, directly target the option:

```js
$('.selectOption4').on('click', function() {
    var id = '#option4';
    $(id).prop('selected', true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
    <option>Option 1</option>
    <option>Option 2</option>
    <option>Option 3</option>
    <option id="option4">Option 4</option>
    <option>Option 5</option>
</select>
<p><a href='#' class='selectOption4'>Select option 4</a></p>
```